# How to increase the TEMP TABLE Space value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, redhat, tablespace

Currently  my Oracle 11g  temp TABLESPACE value is  34GB. I need to increase the table space value to a large value (45GB)

I tired the following sql command to increase the temp table space.

```
    ALTER TABLESPACE temp ADD TEMPFILE '/oradata/temp01.dbf' SIZE  45G
```

The error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01144: File size (5536951 blocks) exceeds maximum of
>   4194303 blocks
>   01144. 00000 -  "File size (%s blocks) exceeds maximum of %s blocks"
>   *Cause:    Specified file size is larger than maximum allowable size value.
>   *Action:   Specify a smaller size.

```
    SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'db_block_size';
```

The  "db_block_size" value is 8192

1. How do I decide the maximum allowed db_block_size and the corresponding temp TABLESPACE value
2. How do I increase the TEMP tablespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, the maximum file size is 4194303 blocks.  If you multiply that out

```
4194303 blocks * 8192 bytes/ block / 1024^3 = 32 GB
```

So you're limited to individual data/ temp files of up to 32 GB.  You can, however, have thousands of data files in a tablespace.  So you could have a 32 GB temp file and another 13 GB temp file or 2 22.5 GB temp files or 9 5 GB temp files.